# How to reset saved data back to defaults?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm implementing saved data on my app by using NSUserDefaults, like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"mySetting",nil]];
// check
int firstLaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"mySetting"];
// set
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"mySetting"];
```

Now for development purposes, I'd like to be able to remove the saved data and go back to the defaults, without having to remove the app and re-install it each single time. Is there a quick way to do that? I thought resetStandardUserDefaults would do the job, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the key which you wish to revert to the default, `-removeObjectForKey:` will remove its definition from the app preferences. All things being equal, this means that subsequent invocations of `-<type>ForKey:` will return the registered default.

Answer (score 10):

The following snippet has worked for me.

```
NSDictionary *defaultsDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
for (NSString *key in [defaultsDict allKeys])
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:key];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Don't think there is any need to call `[defaultsDict allKeys]`, `for in` on a Dictionary iterates the keys

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reloading the defaults after calling reset? as PEZ says:

e.g

```
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

This clears all the defaults and loads in the standard set.

If you only want to blitz one value as it seems from your snippet, then Graham's suggestion of -removeObjectForKey is easier.

**EDIT:** corrected my misuse of class methods.

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that +resetStandardUserDefaults doesn't do what Steph wanted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898301/nsuserdefaults-whats-the-resetstandarduserdefaults-method-good-for-how-can-i

Comment: I agree that your code is more appropriate but this for example doesn't work (while Graham's answer works) : [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
    [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]];
    NSArray *offlinePages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:OFFLINE_PAGES];
It still returns a value in debug. Do you have any idea why ? i downvoted your answer for that reason, if you can explain why this is wrong i will upvote you. Vincent

Comment: I did say Graham's suggestion was more appropriate for resetting a single key. What value are you setting for this key as an application default?

Comment: I find I always have to synchronize after everything to get changes to work, so maybe this:
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Answer (score 0):

The docs has this to say about resetStandardUserDefaults:

> A subsequent invocation of
>   standardUserDefaults creates a new
>   shared user defaults object with the
>   standard search list.

With some positive (wishful?) thinking it looks like that would be what you need. =)

Comment: It also says "Synchronizes any changes made to the shared user defaults object", which is a very strong indication that it isn't what Steph needs.

Comment: Not to reanimate this thread after a long sleep (too late) but I'm in the same boat with regard to resetStandardUserDefaults not doing quite the thing I'd expect it to do with a name like _reset_ :\

Comment: LOL (sorry, I know it's not a laughing matter, just so eloquently put by you).